# Need Assistance Understanding execution of Program

Tags: java, arrays, methods, for-loop

I am reviewing a practice problem and I just want to know the sequence as to how the program came up with an answer of  --->   2 1
I am mostly having trouble understanding the main driver call. I understand the usage of the methods.

The code is:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    increase(x);

    int[] y = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    increase(y[0]);
    System.out.println(x[0] + " " + y[0]);
  }
  public static void increase(int[] x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
      x[i]++;
  }
  public static void increase(int y) {
     y++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Look into scope of variables and passing by value.

Comment: Explain to us what you know and how you think it should work.

Answer (score 4):

The code is demonstrating the difference between (effectively) call-by-reference (in the first increase method) and call-by-value (in the second increase method). In fact, both methods use call-by-value, but in the first case the value is a reference to an object (the array) and in the second case is an `int` (a single value from the array).

The code `int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` creates an array. When you call increase(x) you are calling the first increase method. That method iterates through the elements of the array and increments each one. The line `x[i]++` is equivalent to `x[i] = x[i] + 1`. The results are stored back to the array. By the end of this call, the array now contains `{2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`. Hence `x[0]` is `2`.

In the second call to `increase(int y)` we do not pass in the array, but the *value* of `y[0]`  (i.e. `1`). The method increments the variable `y` but that has no effect outside of the method. In Java, when you pass a variable it is passed by value which essentially means a copy of the value is passed in. Any changes that are made to that value do not affect the original.

When you pass in the array, you pass a reference to the array object. The reference cannot be changed, but the contents of the object (the contents of the array) can be changed.

I have to admit it is a bit confusing, but re-read what I've written a few times and hopefully you'll get it!

Comment: Thank you so much!! I managed to understand the first call of increase(x), but the second call to increase(int y) was really confusing me. I understand it now and will definitely re-read over and over again to completely understand it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

A Java method receives a copy of the value you pass in, in case of a primitive, or a copy of the reference, in case of an object type. `increase(int[])` takes in an array (which is a reference type), and increments each value in that array. The method receives a copy of your array reference, and does not change it. It just increments each element in the array, which is the same array as you sent in.

With `increase(int)` it's a bit different. The `y` variable is a copy of the value you pass in. When you increment `y`, you're just incrementing that copy. The original value is not changed. So the appearance is that the value you pass in is in fact not changed.

Hence, the output will be `2 1`.

Answer (score 0):

In increase(x), you are passing the reference of the array and thus the increment is in fact increasing the actual values. While in the second instance you are passing a specific value of the array and increasing it is not really affecting the value held in the array. For more information, [Check out the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614562/how-to-pass-by-reference-in-java)