# Java - pass a variable by reference

Tags: java, wrapper, pass-by-reference

I wish to send an 'int' to a function that changes its value. I want to send it by reference so the new value of 'int' is kept after returning to the callee. What is the most effective way to do it?

I know that I can use a wrapper class Integer that sends an object of an 'int'. However, I can't figure out how to change the value of this class, so the change will prevail after returning to the callee.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is because Integer is immutable, as it should be. You need to make your own wrapper class.

Comment: Integer class is immutable, so may be you need to create your own class with int as instance variable

Comment: make your method return the modified int value and then set it again.

Comment: OK. So, as far as I understand, there is no built-in method inside Integer class that can handle such a case. Am I right?

Comment: I hope this helps you out.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614562/how-to-pass-by-reference-in-java

Answer (score 3):

[Nothing can be passed by reference in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/106261), you need a wrapper, a conventional bean would do:

```
public class MyWrapper {
int x;
public void setX(int x){
    this.x = x;
  }
}
```