# Java pass value to class

Tags: java

After searching and reading a lot of examples about passing values/objects between classes/methods I still don't get it . . .
Let's say i have this little code (which is wrong):

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Print print = new Print();
    }
}
```

//end of Main class

```
class ClassA{
    int x = 3;
    int y = 5;
    public classA(int a, int b){
        a = x;
        b = y;
    }
}
class ClassB{
    int c;
    public classB(int a, int b){
        c = a * b;
    }
}
class Print{
    int c;
    public Print(int c){
    System.out.println("C is equal to: " + c);
    }
}
```

This code example doesn't work but i want to understand once and forever how does passing values works in java.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do the equivalent of pass by reference for primitives in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614562/how-to-do-the-equivalent-of-pass-by-reference-for-primitives-in-java)

Comment: Your code sample does not compile. Further it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @hotzst *"Your code sample does not compile."* Maybe that's why OP wrote "which is wrong" and "This code example doesn't work"? ...

Comment: @Tom in that case it is badly worded as the title says passing values and the post provides two classes that are never used.

Comment: @hotzst OP doesn't know how to pass a value to the `Print` constructor, so the title is correct.

Comment: Although ClassA and ClassB are not used in the program, maybe the methods `classA` and `classB` should start with a capital C (to become constructors), and in ClassA I think `a=x; b=y;` was intended to be `x=a; y=b;`

Answer (score 1):

Add some int value when you instance `Print` like this:

```
  Print print = new Print(445);
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor must have the exactly same name as the simple name of the class (class name without package). Case sensitive. Use `public ClassA` instead of `public classA` on line 4.

Variable assigning is in this syntax:

```
{target_to_assign_to} = {value_to_assign};
```

You are doing it the opposite way.

Also, you have to pass a value to the `Print()` constructor, as @Abdelhak pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

> Print print = new Print();

In above statement your trying to call default constructor. Which becomes unavailable when you define your own constructors. So either define a default constructor your self and pass a value.

`Print print = new Print(10);`

OR

```
class Print{
    int c;
    public Print(int c){
    System.out.println("C is equal to: " + c);
    }
    public Print(){
    System.out.println(" Handles : new Print() ");
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't define a default constructor, only a non-argument constructor.

Comment: Hey Tom.. I would like to whats the difference ? anyway thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The difference? One is provided by the compiler, and the other by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you never call ClassA and ClassB (you also have to write the constructor of a class exactly like it; so ClassA instead of classA), so you can basically remove them.

Now about passing values. You actually never pass a value. When creating an object you can pass arguments to the constructor of the class the object belongs to. So when you create a new Print object in your Main class, you have to pass the constructor of the Print class a value.

```
Print print = new Print(5); //5 is the value you pass
```

Another thing that is probably confusing for you: You set `int c` in your Print class, which means it as an attribute. Every Print object you create will have an int which you can access by `printObject.c` for example you could write

```
Print print = new Print(5); // Sets your locale variable c for printing it to 5
print.c = 5; // Sets the attribute c to 5
```

It would be way less confusig, if you would name them differently. Like this:

```
class Print {
  int myInt;
  public Print(int c){
    System.out.println("C is equal to: " + c);
  }
}
```

If you actually want to set the attribute myInt (you called it c) to a value you pass to the constructor, the code would look like this:

```
class Print{
  int myInt;
  public Print(int c){
    this.myInt = c; // Sets the value of the attribute myInt to the value of c
    System.out.println("C is equal to: " + c); // Prints out the value you passed
  }
}
```