# return boolean in function in java

Tags: java

i make a small program in java about Metro Station in Egypt
so i specified the lines the passeger take a metro from it and the line they go to by boolean 
in default at classes boolean value is false
but i want to make 4 variable changing in Main

this code specify the index of the stations in line 1 and make source1 true in the same time 
it works if i write it inline 
but when i write it in function 
always source1 is false as defualt 
and i can solve it 
please help

```
public void Searchinline1(String []line1,String sourceStation,String destinationStation,boolean source1,boolean destination1,int sourceindex,int destinationindex) {

    for (int i = 0; i < line1.length; i++) {
        if (sourceStation.equalsIgnoreCase(line1[i])) {
            source1=true;
            sourceindex=i;
        }
        if (destinationStation.equalsIgnoreCase(line1[i])) {
            destination1=true;
            destinationindex=i;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post the link of "equalsIgnoreCase" method? And what do you want to achieve?

Comment: did not understand..could you provide expected output with current output

Comment: In Java, the method parameters are passed by value not by reference.

Comment: Setting `source1=true` and/or `destination1=true` has no effect outside of the method.

Comment: source1 in the method is not equals to the boolean that you declared in the class. You should consider using `this.source1` and `this.destination1` instead.

Comment: While the *fact* that the variables are passed by value is what is causing your problem, the question then becomes, are you attempting to return just the boolean, or all three of the boolean, destination index, and source index?

Comment: If your bool variables and int indexes are declared in some class, access it directly by Object.source1, etc.. instead of sending as parameter.

Comment: @JoãoVilaça i write this method to ignore if some one write - sadat station instead of Sadat station

Comment: @jWeaver 
the output is 
the station between the source and destination
and the time between them

Comment: You should change your class variables by refering to 'this'. And you can have that function return an array of booleans, with your answer, and then access it from within other method.

Comment: @JoãoVilaça "equalsIgnoreCase" is in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-

Comment: did a quick search and got [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614562/how-to-do-the-equivalent-of-pass-by-reference-for-primitives-in-java) The checked answer will help.

Comment: @Dylan 
it works , thank alot

Comment: @Makoto 
no destination index and source index is int

Comment: @Sgene9 
yes it works , thanks alot ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare variables in your class and use `this` to change it's value. 
`this.source1 = true;`

### According to oracle

`Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called.`

You can read official doc for this keyword http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html