# How to pass the value by reference in java

Tags: java, function, parameter-passing

```
public class JavaApplication6 {

    public static void a(int b)
    {
        b++;
    }
```

I am calling the function `a` and passing the variable `b` with the intention of incrementing it like a C++ reference (`&b`).  Will this work? If not, why?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int b=0;
        a(b);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: but why is that i can do it in c++ by just passing the variable to function by reference is there any way of doing it except global declaration

Comment: In Java it's pass by value and hence you cant change the value of b. Whereas in programming language like C, C++, you can pass pointer and using pointer you can increment the value.

Comment: please tell me any alternative i can use

Comment: still no gain it is not working "java.lang.Integer"

Comment: This is generally a bad idea, and leads to complex unreadable code.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Java is strictly pass-by-value without exception, so this isn't possible.

Comment: Java is _only_ pass by value/copy. For more, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Comment: You can't "natively" do this, but you could define your own `MyInt` class with a single reference of a member variable `int b` that you can modify

Comment: Yeah like many others have said Java is designed to have _no_ pass-by-reference

Comment: @cricket_007 There is already a java class that does this called AtomicInteger. See my answer for more details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614562/how-to-do-the-equivalent-of-pass-by-reference-for-primitives-in-java

Answer (score 3):

While you can't really accomplish that with `int` (the primitive type for integer), you can accomplish something very similar with [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). Simply invoke the [getAndIncrement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndIncrement()) method on an instance of the class. Something like this:

```
public static void a(AtomicInteger b) {
    b.getAndIncrement();
}
```

(Note that you also can't do this with java.lang.Integer, because java.lang.Integer is an immutable class.)

Comment: You can do this for any data type with an `AtomicReference`. It's far from idiomatic Java, though, and is generally discouraged.

Comment: While this accomplishes the task, using `AtomicInteger` just to use its mutable property is probably not the best idea because of the non-blocking sync overhead.

Answer (score 3):

First of all: Java does not allow for pass-by-reference. Further, *out-parameters* (when a function's calculations/results are placed in one or more of the variables passed to it) are not used; instead, something is `return`ed from a method like so:

```
b = a(b);
```

Otherwise, in Java, you pass objects as pointers ([which are incorrectly called references](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)). Unfortunately (in your case) most types corresponding to `int` (`Integer`, `BigInteger`, etc.) are immutable, so you cannot change the properties in the object without creating a new one. You can, however, make your own implementation:

```
public static class MutableInteger {
    public int value;

    public MutableInteger(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MutableInteger b = new MutableInteger(2);
    increment(b);
    System.out.println(b.value);
}

public static void increment(MutableInteger mutableInteger) {
    mutableInteger.value++;
}
```

The following will be printed to the console when this code is run:

```
3
```

At the end of the day, using the above requires a **strong** argument on the programmer's part.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with primitive types like int, because Java passes primitives by value. Simply wrap `b` in a mutable container object :

```
class Holder {
  int b;
}
```

Now you can modify the value  by doing :

```
public static void a(Holder h) {
  h.b++;
}
```

You should, however, consider to work with [Immutable Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html), which are generally considered a good thing in Java to avoid side effects and concurrency issues.

Comment: `h.b = h.b++;` seriously?

Comment: No; it does nothing.  The postfix increment operator returns the original value.

Comment: Ups. Corrected.

Comment: But why not just `h.b++;` ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a value by reference in Java. If a primitive is passed to a method, the JVM passes it by value. If it is an object that is sent to a method, the JVM creates a copy of the its reference. Since this is a "copy" the modification won't change the initial object.  But still, there are workaround such as using the AtomicInteger suggested in  the previous posts.