# Regarding java references

Tags: java

When I going through java tutorials I got an idea about the pointers are not used in java. but java internally uses pointers, but when we look through developer perspective java supports references only. Then why java does not support pass by reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java does manipulate objects by reference, and all object variables are references. However, Java doesn't pass method arguments by reference; it passes them by value.

[Source](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html)

[How to do the equivalent of pass by reference for primitives in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614562/how-to-do-the-equivalent-of-pass-by-reference-for-primitives-in-java)

[Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: Well, you could just post a comment to point the duplicate (or flag the question if you can), there is no point to recreate a new question thread about this. (especially with a question with +4500 upvotes)

Answer (score 3):

All object variables are just references, so when you pass an object you're actually passing by reference (technically you're passing a reference variable which gets copied by value). The only things that are passed by value are primitive types like int.

Comment: Cannot agree with "All objects are just references", but can agree "All object variables are just references"

Comment: ...ok, I'll edit it.

Comment: I find your answer misleading, you said only primitives are passed by value. "References" to objects instance are pass by value. Or you would be able to reinstanciate a parameter in a method to that reference. This subject requires a lot of explanation to be complete.

Comment: I don't think the questioner requires a complete and fully detailed answer, and I did address your issue in my parenthetical. Feel free to give a full explanation if you like, but I suspect it is not what is needed here!

Comment: @DuncanThacker that's because you opened the problem without going into the explanation that bother me. Well I already address my explanation by flagging the duplicate actually ;)

Comment: @DuncanThacker  thanks for your comment. Actually  that was what I need. :-)