# How these two codes snippets are different?

Tags: java, optimization, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

The second code is working fine whereas the first code is returning 0 every time. Why is it so?

In the first code snippet I am passing 'ans' variable by reference to the 'height' method, which suppose to modify passed 'ans' variable.

```
class Solution {
    public int diameterOfBinaryTree(TreeNode root) {
        int ans=0;
        if(root==null)return 0;
        height(root,ans);
        return ans;
    }
    
    public int height(TreeNode root,int ans){
        if(root==null)return 0;
        
        int L=height(root.left,ans);
        int R=height(root.right,ans);
        ans = Math.max(ans,L+R);

        return 1+Math.max(L,R);
    }
}
```

Below code works fine.

```
class Solution {
int ans=0;
    public int diameterOfBinaryTree(TreeNode root) {
        if(root==null )return 0;
        height(root);
        return ans;
    }
    
    public int height(TreeNode root){
        if(root==null)return 0;

        int L=height(root.left);
        int R=height(root.right); 
        ans=Math.max(ans,L+R);

        return 1+Math.max(L,R);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In first example you are passing [`primitive`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) value to another method and trying to change it there, it won't work.

[How to do the equivalent of pass by reference for primitives in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5614562/15777370)